# Prolog greek letters inside write

Tags: prolog

Below is part of my code.I want to change the content of write in greek letters.

Can anyone tell me the way?

```
collect_results:-
    write('Give a number from 1 to 5 : '),
    read(X),nl,
    check(X).
```

Comment: Why can't you type Greek letters the way you usually do?

Comment: Syntax error:layout_inside_quotes

Comment: What's the encoding of your file? Try UTF-8 (without and with a BOM). I don't think ISO 8859-7 will work well, but maybe it does.

Answer (score 0):

Works on my system (swi-prolog 7.2.3 on linux mint 18):

```prolog
?- ['user'].
collect_results :- 
  write('Παρακαλώ διαλέξτε ένα νούμερο από 1 εώς 5: '), 
  read(X), nl, 
  write('Το νούμερο που διαλέξατε είναι το '), write(X), nl.

?- collect_results.
Παρακαλώ διαλέξτε ένα νούμερο από 1 εώς 5: 3.

Το νούμερο που διαλέξατε είναι το 3
true.
```

What system / terminal / locale are you running in?
What is the output of: `prolog_flag(encoding, Encoding).` ?